# Forcing VNC to use more bandwidth

Tags: vnc, bandwidth

I'm trying to access a Windows computer on my 100Mbit LAN with TightVNC server on a Windows 7 box, and using vnc4viewer on the Linux machine; I have also tried the Java TightVNC viewer.  However it's *very* slow: clicking is only recognized half of the time, moving windows is too slow to really do.

If however I access the same computer from *outside* the network, it's much faster.

1. Could I be missing a reason for it to be so slow? Network usage is under 0.44%. CPU usage is under 2% across all cores.
2. If there's no problem, how can I tell it "it's okay to use more bandwidth"?

Comment: Exactly which server and clients are being compared? Also, why not RDP?

Comment: @afrazier : I want to be able to use 3d applications; RDP actually replaces the video driver in Windows with a software device that outright denies any 3d.  I am using TightVNC server on the Windows box, and the Java viewer on the Linux box. I also tried the viewer xvnc4viewer.

Comment: You tried xvnc4viewer and got the same result - poor performance?

Comment: @Paul: Yes.  I just tried UltraVNC on my WIndows box with the driver installed and it's still just as bad.